# JS regex test with validate input

Tags: javascript, regex

```
/\w+/.test('@asd') // true
/\w+/.test('@') // false
/\w+/.test('asd') // true
```

Shouldn't the first one return false as well? consider there is a special character inside the string.

I did read thought the doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test probably missed something important

> The test() method executes a search for a match between a regular
>   expression and a specified string. Returns true or false.

please correct me on which part am i missing here to not getting the expected result.

Comment: `asd` inside the string matches, so no, the match doesn't fail. Your third line is incorrect too, `/\w+/.test('asd') // false` gives `true`

Comment: Thanks @CertainPerformance how can i made it search the entire string and return false.

Comment: @Bill Anchor it. `/^\w+$/.test('@asd')`

Comment: thanks @mpen oh i see, i guess you will have to do that way, is there another JS api which will do that? match?

Comment: @Bill No, there aren't any built-in methods that add the `^` and `$` as far as I'm aware. You can write one, but it's not quite as pretty.

Comment: Thanks very much @mpen for your help.